# 'cfgrib' is not showing in xarray engine list, when the python code is packaged with pyinstaller to get exe file

Tags: pyinstaller, python-xarray, cfgrib

I am trying to create an executable file from python code with 'Pyinstaller' package. The code runs in conda environment where the cfgrib selfcheck is good:
Found: eccodes v2.27.0.
your system is ready

However when the executable created by pyinstaller runs, the error is:
ValueError: unrecognized engine cfgrib must be one of: ['scipy','store']

I adde 'eccodes', 'python-eccodes', 'cfgrib', 'netcdf4' to the hidden imports, but no success. Does anybody have any idea to fix this issue!

Comment: create an [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with xarray and installing it with the extra "complete" solved my issue:

```
pip3 install xarray[complete]
```

It is not obvious that you are not installing the whole package without the extra.